# Resetting array index when reaching the last index

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a code in which the 12 months of the calendar are in an array, the code then asks for a month, and then it outputs the 10 months ahead of the inputted month.

```
e.g.   
input: January   
output: February, March,...November
```

I'm having trouble reverting the index back to the start once the index exceeds 12, for example, if I input August, it's supposed to output September to June, but instead it stops at December and says out of bounds. Thank you

```
   String months[];
   String choice;
   months = new String[13];
   months[0] = null ;
   months[1] = "January";
   months[2] = "February";
   months[3] = "March";
   months[4] = "April";
   months[5] = "May";
   months[6] = "June";
   months[7] = "July";
   months[8] = "August";
   months[9] = "September";
   months[10] = "October";
   months[11] = "November";
   months[12] = "December";
   System.out.print("Enter Month : ");
   choice = a.nextLine();

   if (choice.equals("August")) {
       for(int i=8; i<i+10; i++) {
           String result= months[i];
           System.out.println(result);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulus when choosing the month to print:

```
int start = 8;
if ("August".equals(choice)) {
    for(int i=start; i < start+10; i++) {
        String result= months[i % 12];
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

This assumes you have defined your `months` array as:

```
String[] months = new String[12];
months[0] = "January";
months[1] = "February";
// ...
months[11] = "December";
```

The idea here is to wrap around the index used to select a month from the array.  The dummy variable `i`, upon hitting the value 12, will wrap around to zero again.

Side note: It is always better to compare a string literal to a variable by placing the literal on the LHS of the comparison.  The version I used is immune to a null pointer exception; the version you used is not.

Answer (score 1):

Use modulus to reset the array index. The solution given above is correct. But if you want to continue with your own defined `months` array, where `months[0] = null ;`, just start the for loop from the next index of the input month.

```
if ("August".equals(choice)) {
    int start = 9;
    for(int i=start; i < start+11; i++) {
        if(i!=13){
            String result= months[i % 13];
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String months[];
        String choice;
        months = new String[13];
        months[0] = null;
        months[1] = "January";
        months[2] = "February";
        months[3] = "March";
        months[4] = "April";
        months[5] = "May";
        months[6] = "June";
        months[7] = "July";
        months[8] = "August";
        months[9] = "September";
        months[10] = "October";
        months[11] = "November";
        months[12] = "December";
        System.out.print("Enter Month : ");
        choice = scanner.nextLine();

        int startIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(months[i])) {
                startIndex = i + 1;
            }
        }

        for (int j = startIndex; j < months.length; j++) {
            String result = months[j];
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
```